# Can I change gender upon starting a New Game Plus?

Tags: persona-3-portable

I just bought P3P for my PS Vita on the PSN and upon starting a new game, I was notified that the gender influences the story somewhat.

New players should start as the male protagonist, while the female protagonist offers a different viewpoint for veterans of Persona 3.

Since I'm new to Persona 3, I decided to follow that recommendation in order to enjoy P3P to its fullest. I was wondering however, if I could choose to go with the female protagonist after beating the game and upon starting a New Game Plus; if not, I'd just play by alternating between both protagonists, in order to follow the story from both perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is nothing else to say on the matter.